Notion public integration fails to duplicate template on user's workspace
I have a template that i want to be duplicated to users workspace during authorization, but instead of notion duplicating the page it only shows a link to the template (View of Journal) instead of the template copy itself.
This makes the returned duplicated_template_id to not work. ie notion page not to be found.

I have tried updating the template site settings by toggling allow duplicate and editting and also updating integration capabilities.
